# Form datetime select field in Laravel 4.1

Tags: laravel-4

My model has an event_datetime field which I want to set on the form using datetime select fields. Rails has [datetime_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-datetime_select) which outputs the following and saves to a MySQL datetime column.

[image: datetime select]

Must default to the current date and work on a shared add/edit form.

No javascript datepickers please.

Comment: `datetime_select("trip", "departing", default: 0.days.from_now)` will this work ??

Comment: Thanks but to clarify this is a Laravel question, not Rails. I have mentioned Rails as an example as it solves this problem so well, and that's what I'm used to so was hoping for an equivalent. Couldn't find anything in Laravel docs to tackle this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to you

```
{{ Form::datetime('event_date') }}
```

And place this macro into some autoloaded file (or view file)

```
Form::macro('datetime', function($name) {
    $years = value(function() {
        $startYear = (int) date('Y');
        $endYear = $startYear - 5;
        $years = ['' => 'year'];
        for($year = $startYear; $year > $endYear; $year--) {
            $years[ $year ] = $year;
        };
        return $years;
    });

    $months = value(function() {
        $months = ['' => 'month'];
        for($month = 1; $month < 13; $month++) {
            $timestamp = strtotime(date('Y'). '-'.$month.'-13');
            $months[ $month ] = strftime('%B', $timestamp);
        }
        return $months;
    });

    $days = value(function() {
        $days = ['' => 'day'];
        for($day = 1; $day < 32; $day++) {
            $days[ $day ] = $day;
        }
        return $days;
    });

    $hours = value(function() {
        $hours = ['' => 'hour'];
        for($hour = 0; $hour < 24; $hour++) {
            $hours[ $hour ] = $hour;
        }
        return $hours;
    });

    $minutes = value(function() {
        $minutes = ['' => 'minute'];
        for($minute = 0; $minute < 60; $minute++) {
            $minutes[ $minute ] = $minute;
        }
        return $minutes;
    });

    return Form::select($name.'[year]', $years) .
        Form::select($name.'[month]', $months) .
        Form::select($name.'[day]', $days) . ' - ' .
        Form::select($name.'[hour]', $hours) .
        Form::select($name.'[minute]', $minutes);
});
```